# access local file with jquery in client side of a Django project

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, file

I need to access a local file on the client side of a Django project and read an xml file from the client's local disk.  Like `C:\\test.xml`

I am doing this in a single html and script file and using Chrome `--allow-file-access` to get permission for this access and it works but when I move this code into my Django project and use this jquery script in my html templates, it does not work and shows cross origin request ... error.

Please help me.  Why is this happening and what is the solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Generally, browsers will simply not allow code loaded from remote servers to access local files. A "solution" to the that, if it existed, would be treated as a critical security bug and fixed as quickly as possible by any and all browser maintainers affected.

Answer (score 0):

One viable option that would work and not set out security alarms all over the place, would be to use `file` form field on your page and ask an end user to give that file to you.

Then, you can use HTML5 `File API` and do whatever you need in javascript or send it to your server.